# Django can't find my custom template filter

Tags: python, django, filter, django-templates

I'm trying to create a custom template filter in my Django app. I've created a templatetags folder under my app, added an `__init__.py` file and a filters.py file with my filters, like so:

```
import os
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def filename(pathname):
    """ Returns the file's name, without folder """
    return os.path.basename(pathname)
```

When I try to access the filter from a template, I get the error "Invalid filter 'filename'"

This question has been asked a lot, so I already checked the following:

- `__init__.py` is properly named
- After opening a shell with `manage.py shell` I can import my filter like so: `import app.templatetags`
- I can also use the filter properly from the Django shell
- I have restarted the Django development server.
- I have placed a breakpoint on the call to `template.library()` - the debugger doesn't stop there.

Here is the template (I've removed parts of it, but the error persists in this small version, as well)

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url lab.views.new.artefact_drop_web tempfile_id=tempfile.id %}" method="post"> 
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <h3>File:</h3>
    <p>{{ tempfile.file.name|filename }}</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your template as well?

Comment: Posted. This is of course s slimmed down version of the template.

Comment: The gotcha for me was manually restarting the django server after creating the templatetag file.  Great summary of things to check for!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `{% load name_of_file_tags_are_in %}` inside your template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Unbelievable! For some reason I was under the impression I only needed to do this with custom tags. Thanks!

Comment: 19 seconds. They should really stop doing that, some answers may be left unaccepted because people got tired.

Comment: You can also use `django.template.add_to_builtins()` to make your filter available without having to `{% load %}` it explicitly.

Comment: For somehow `{% load %}` doesn't work for me, but `add_to_builtins` is perfectly fine.

Comment: load also doesn't work for me, why is this happening?

Comment: Thanks is a important tip.